# How do I show a specific web design to a user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js

for example if a user is an admin how do implement react logic to show a diffrent design or if a user is privileged and I want to change his page design And authenticate his privilege using node + Passport.js. How should I go about implementing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general way I go about this is have a layer of routes exposed post authentication only. Something like below.

```js
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/admin">
        <AdminView />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
}

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticatedStatus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // business logic or api calls here
    setAuthenticatedStatus(true); // assuming valid user
  }, []); // keep necessary dependencies

  if(isAuthenticated) return <Routes />;

  return <UserNeedsPermission />;

}
```

Some people also go about this with an HoC approach at component level, that is also another possible way, but it might not be needed though, something like

```js
const Admin = () => (<div>Admin View</div>);

const withAuthentication = (Comp) => (props) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticatedStatus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // business logic or api calls here
    setAuthenticatedStatus(true); // assuming valid user
  }, []); // keep necessary dependencies

  if(isAuthenticated) return <Comp {...props} />

  return <UserNeedsAuthentication />;

}

export default withAuthentication(Admin);
```