# How can I check if login is successful, then display the protected routes in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

After successful login how can I see/access `Dashboard, CreatedLink` components mentioned inside the protected route. Could someone please advise how do I check
`loginEmail` is available in localStorage then display the above components else display login. Do I need another component for navigation to achieve this ?

`App.js`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard";
import CreateLink from "./components/createLink";
import Nominate from "./components/nominate";
import Login from "./components/login";
import { ProtectedRoute } from "./components/protectedRoute";
import ErrorPage from "./components/errorPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <div>
          <div className="navbar-nav">

          </div>
          <Switch>
              <ProtectedRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
              <ProtectedRoute exact path='/createLink' component={CreateLink} />
              <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
              <Route path='/nominate/:token' component={Nominate} />
              <Route path='/errorPage' component={ErrorPage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`login.js`

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useGoogleLogin  } from 'react-google-login';
import { refreshToken } from '../utils/refreshToken';

const clientId ="client_id_here";

const Login = () => {

    const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState("");

    const onSuccess = (res) =>{
        console.log("Login successfully",res.profileObj);
        const email = res.profileObj.email;
        setUserEmail(email);
        window.localStorage.setItem("loginEmail", email);
        refreshToken(res);
    }
    const onFailure = (res) => {
        console.log('Login failed: res:', res);
        alert(
            `Failed to login !`
        );
    };
    const {signIn} = useGoogleLogin ({
        onSuccess,
        onFailure,
        clientId,
        isSignedIn: true,
        accessType: 'offline',
    })

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div className="inputForm">
                <button onClick={signIn}>
                    <img src="images/google.png" className="loginG"/>
                    <span className="loginText">Sign in</span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>

    )
}

export default Login;
```

`protectedRoute.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                if (localStorage.getItem("loginEmail")) {
                    return <Component {...props} />;
                } else {
                    return (
                        <>
                            <Redirect
                                to={{
                                    pathname: "/",
                                    state: {
                                        from: props.location,
                                    },
                                }}
                            />
                        </>
                    );
                }
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

**Sandboxlink**

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-forest-4csz3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you once refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67545327/how-do-i-show-a-specific-web-design-to-a-user/67545430#67545430
We can discuss ahead from there.

Comment: Your code seems to run correctly. I skipped the google auth check and wired the login button to your success handler and I see localStorage update. When unauthenticated and try to access "/dashboard" I'm bounced back to "/", and when authenticated I'm allowed in to "/dashboard". I'm not sure what your issue/question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be routed back to the protected route originally being accessed before getting bounced to the login route.

The protected route passed a referrer, i.e. `from` value in route state, you just need to access this value and imperatively redirect back to the original route.

login

Access the `location.state` and `history` objects to get the referrer value and redirect to it. This destructures `from` from `location.state` object and provides a fallback to the "/dashboard" route if the referrer is undefined (i.e. user navigated directly to "/login").

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { state: { from = "/dashboard" } = {} } = useLocation();

  ...

  const onSuccess = (res) => {
    console.log("Login successfully", res.profileObj);
    const email = res.profileObj.email;
    setUserEmail(email);
  window.localStorage.setItem("loginEmail", email);
  // refreshToken(res);
  history.replace(from);
};
```

I also think a small refactor of your `PrivateRoute` component will allow you to first check localStorage when landing on a protected route.

```
export const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
  return localStorage.getItem("loginEmail") ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: "/",
        state: {
          from: props.location
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-check-if-login-is-successful-then-display-the-protected-routes-in-rea]

Comment: Appreciate your reply. I will try the above way reply. By the way how does ``const { state: { from = "/" } = {} } = useLocation();`` this work ? I mean is that path is assigned to a state called ``from`` which is accessed by useLocation() ? My bad, I didn't quite get the above solution ?

Comment: @soccerway No worries. `state: { from = "/" }` is a way to destructure the route state `from` value, providing a fallback value in case `from` is undefined, and the additional `= {}` provides a default value in the case the `location.state` itself is undefined. This covers the case that a user navigated to "/login" directly so there won't be any route state to access.

Comment: Ok now I have tried your solution and I have logged in with my google mail but still I am not redirected to my protected routes ! it still stays in my login page. Ideally once login is succesfully I should see the Dashboard and CreateLink right ?

Comment: @soccerway Are you trying to navigate to "/dashboard" or "/createLink" first while unauthenticated (to create the referrer, get redirected to "/login", authenticate, and redirect back) or are you just going straight to "/login"?

Comment: Login is my landing page ie, ''/'', in the Login page i have Google SignIn button, once signed is successfully I should be navigated to the Dashboard and Create Link. Without sign in I should still be in Login page.

Comment: @soccerway Yes, but are you trying to navigate to dashboard or create link first? This is how the auth redirects work. If you just go to "/login" it won't know where you want to go afterwards. If you just want to always navigate somewhere after successful login then it can only be one destination, it can't redirect to both dashboard and create link. I'll update answer and linked codesandbox to fallback redirect to "/dashboard" when there is no redirect referrer.

Comment: Thank you Drew, I have accepted the answer I want to redirect to ``/dashboard``